# Angular - Unable to call a method on `keypress` event in mat-select

Tags: angular, angular-material

I was trying to select the value on click of `mat-option` using keyboard but it is not working. Can anyone let me know why `mat-select` is not working for `keypress`?

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="legacy">
  <mat-select role="listbox" placeholder="Start time" [disabled]="isEventAllday" [value]="startTime.displayVal">
  <mat-option role="option" required *ngFor="let time of timeVals, let i = index" (click)="startTimeSelected(time, i)"
    (keypress)="startTimeSelected(time, i)" [value]="time.displayVal">{{time.displayVal}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: [Keypress is considered deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event) Have you tried with keydown or keyup?

Comment: Is this a reactive or template-driven form? In either case you could make do with the `selectionChange` event of `mat-select` instead of the built-in JS events like `click` and `keyup`.

Comment: @MichaelD selectionChange is worked! Thank you :)